# New-AzureSBAuthorizationRule error when creating authorization for a Service Bus Queue

Tags: powershell, azure, azureservicebus, azure-powershell, azure-servicebus-queues

I use New-AzureSBAuthorizationRule to create a new Shared Access Policy for an Azure Service Bus Queue. See command below...

```
New-AzureSBAuthorizationRule -EntityName abcdef -EntityType Queue -Permission Listen  -Name "abcdef_reader" -Namespace abcdefnamespace
```

But every time I run this I get the error below:

```
New-AzureSBAuthorizationRule : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzureSBAuthorizationRule -EntityName abcdef -EntityType Queue -Permission ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureSBAuthorizationRule], NullReferenceException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.ServiceBus.NewAzureSBAuthorizationRuleCommand
```

I am able to run New-AzureSBAuthorizationRule without issues if I drop EntityName and EntityType, i.e. creating policies for the Service Bus and not the Queue.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I get the same error and use

```
            function Create-AzureSBAuthorisationTopic
            {
            param
            ([Parameter (Mandatory = $true)]
            [string] $Namespace,
            [Parameter (Mandatory = $true)]
            [string] $TopicName,
            [Parameter (Mandatory = $true)]
            [string]$RuleName,
             [switch]$CanManage,
             [switch]$CanListen,
             [switch]$CanSend

            )

            $NamespaceManager = [Microsoft.ServiceBus.NamespaceManager]::CreateFromConnectionString($CurrentNamespace.ConnectionString);

            $newkey = [Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.SharedAccessAuthorizationRule]::GenerateRandomKey()

                #Strongly Typed Array
                [Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.AccessRights[]]$AccessRights =  
                New-Object -TypeName "System.Collections.Generic.List[Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.AccessRights]" ;



                    if ($CanManage)
                    {
                        $AccessRights  +=  [Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.AccessRights]::Manage;
                    }

                    if ($CanListen)
                    {
                        $AccessRights  += [Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.AccessRights]::Listen;
                    }

                    if ($CanSend)
                    {

                        $AccessRights  += [Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.AccessRights]::Send;
                    }    


            $AuthorizationRule = [Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.SharedAccessAuthorizationRule]::new($RuleName,$newkey, $accessRights)
            $AuthorizationRule
            $topic = $NamespaceManager.GetTopic($TopicName)
            $topic.Authorization.Add($AuthorizationRule)
            $NamespaceManager.UpdateTopic($topic)
            }
```

You can alter the code to set permissions on Queues by replacing topic with queue :-)

Answer (score -1):

is it possible you're missing some syntax around the -Permission parameter? Here's an example of the PS command line given on MSDN:

C:\PS>New-AzureSBAuthorizationRule -Name MyRule -Namespace MyNamespace **-Permission $("Manage", "Listen", "Send")** -EntityName MyEntity -EntityType Queue -PrimaryKey P+lL/Mnd2Z9sj5hwMrRyAxQDdX8RHfbdqU2eIAqs1rc=

Looks like your parameter should be **-Permission $("Listen")**

Please let us know if that helps.

Regards,
Seth Manheim
Azure Doc Team

Comment: I did try that before but I revalidated and it still doesn't work. I hadn't included the PrimaryKey in my previous calls, but when I did that now I still got the same message.

Comment: This will create a policy on the namespace and not at the Queue level